VECM analysis interpretation of ECT coefficients
Can I say that ect1 is significant as 91,42% of values returns to equilibrium after one period? I'm not sure if I can make any reliable interpretation even if results for ect1 is logical, given that for ect2-8 values are non-logical and model find some of them significant.
Results:
ect1 = -9.142e-01***
ect2 = 5.191e+01***
ect3 = -3.894e+00***
ect4 = -4.152e+00**
ect5 = 1.302e+00
ect6 = 6.827e+01
ect7 = 1.408e+01***
ect8 = 1.292e+04
Model multiple R-squared: 0.5309
Can I make interpretation for ect1 from this model or given the model results the whole model is not reliable?

It is not entirely clear without more details and context, but your interpretation is incorrect.
ECT would usually mean the (lagged, signed) distance from the equilibrium, and there should not be significance attached to it. Are you reporting the slope coefficients on the ECTs? If so, for ECT1 it means the left-hand-side variable moves 92% of the way towards (or maybe away from?) the equilibrium in one period. Towards vs. away from is determined by the sign of the ECT and the sign with which the LHS variable enters in the ECT.
